# Few spans are going crazy

Tags: css, html

I have few spans on my website , and i'm trying to make them go on the place I want them to , but it isn't going well as of now .

My HTML code:

```
<span class="forumname"><a href="./forum1.aspx">מה שבראש</a></span><br />
<span class="forumname"><a href="./forum2.aspx">מה שבלב</a></span><br />
<span class="forumname"><a href="./forum3.aspx">תמונות הגולשים</a></span><br />
<span class="forumname"><a href="./forum4.aspx">סקרים</a></span><br />
<span class="forumname"><a href="./forum5.aspx">אקטואליה</a></span><br />
<span class="forumname"><a href="./forum8.aspx">יהדות ותורה</a></span><br />
<span class="forumname"><a href="./forum9.aspx">אתאיזם</a></span><br />
<span class="forumname"><a href="./forum10.aspx">צבא וביטחון</a></span><br />
```

forumname Class in CSS :

```
.forumname {
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 14px;
position: relative;
top: 77px;
left: 720px;
font-weight: bold;
margin-top: 80px; }
```

And this is the result :

[image: The result]

How can I align all of the spans so they can all start from the same position on the right ? Please Help me , i've tried everything , and i'm going crazy !
I tryed adding direction: rtl; to the span class, float: right and left; but with no success .

Thank you in advance ,
Iliya Vaitzman .

Answer (score 1):

Just set text `text-align: right` on the parent element - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fbLPz/)

Comment: With your help , i made it okay .. I used direction: rtl; on the parent element . Thank you So MUCH!

Answer (score 0):

That really needs to be a list, spans is just the absolute  wrong way to do it...
http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/xUSdv/1/

```
<ul>
<li><a href="./forum1.aspx">מה שבראש</a></li>
<li><a href="./forum2.aspx">מה שבלב</a></li>
<li><a href="./forum3.aspx">תמונות הגולשים</a></li>
<li><a href="./forum4.aspx">סקרים</a></li>
<li><a href="./forum5.aspx">אקטואליה</a></li>
<li><a href="./forum8.aspx">יהדות ותורה</a></li>
<li><a href="./forum9.aspx">אתאיזם</a></li>
<li><a href="./forum10.aspx">צבא וביטחון</a></li>
</ul>


li a{
color: black;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 14px;
position: relative;
font-weight: bold;
margin-top: 80px;}
li{ list-style-type:disc;
margin-right:100px;}
ul{ 
text-align:right;}
```